# « Elles entrèrent dans une chambre tendue d'étoffe perse [...] » chez Dumas fils : pourquoi c'est le féminin singulier de la couleur ?

Tags: adjectifs, histoire, genre, littérature, homonymes

On a l'adjectif de couleur [**pers**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pers), *entre le vert et le bleu*, de registre littéraire ([Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/pers/59769?q=pers#59405)), qu'on associe aux yeux de Minerve/d'[Athéna](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ath%C3%A9na) en mythologie. On a des emplois avec l'accord de l'adjectif en genre, au féminin, *perse* : « [*quatre amours de robes*] *il y en avait une perse et une [puce](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/puce)* [marron tirant sur le brun-rouge] » (Musset). Au LBU (*Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>, § 555) on donne des exemples où le féminin est attesté pour la couleur, dont un extrait d'une œuvre d'Alexandre Dumas fils :

> Du reste, il y avait de quoi faire des emplettes. Le mobilier était
>   superbe. Meubles de bois de rose et de Boule, vases de Sèvres et de
>   Chine, statuettes de Saxe, satin, velours et dentelle, rien n'y
>   manquait.
>
> Je me promenai dans l'appartement et je suivis les nobles curieuses
>   qui m'y avaient précédé. Elles entrèrent dans une chambre tendue
>   d'étoffe perse, et j'allais y entrer aussi, quand elles en sortirent
>   presque aussitôt en souriant et comme si elles eussent eu honte de
>   cette nouvelle curiosité. [...]
>
> [ [*La dame aux camélias*](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6572546p/f42.item.r=perse) (aussi [ici](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2419/2419-h/2419-h.htm)), Alexandre Dumas fils,
>   1848. ]

Il y a homonymie et [*perse*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/perse/1) veut aussi dire qui se rapporte à la Perse ancienne, tel l'adjectif [persan](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/persan) ; *art perse/persan* figure aux deux vedettes du TLFi. Le verbe [*tendre*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tendre) peut signifier *recouvrir le(s) mur(s)*, « [d]ans une petite pièce [...] on avait tendu un papier vert [...] » (Daudet), ou *tapisser*, « [e]lle [...], tendit à nouveau son appartement, l'embellit de fleurs » (Balzac).

---

- Qu'est-ce qui fait dire que l'auteur (Dumas) parle de la couleur *pers(e)* et
  non de l'origine de l'étoffe (*perse/persane*) ; un syntagme avec *tendre*  dans le sens dont on a discuté ou avec *étoffe* oriente-t-il un apport en qualification ou en complémentation particulier au profit d'une sémantique ou d'une autre ?
- Le contexte de la phrase, la connaissance de l’[œuvre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Dame_aux_cam%C3%A9lias) en particulier (aussi
  de [*La Traviata*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_traviata) de Verdi), de l'ensemble de l’œuvre de [Dumas
  fils](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandre_Dumas_fils) et de son style sont-ils d'un quelconque
  secours ici ; la certitude pour la couleur reposerait-elle sur une
  preuve documentaire des lieux associés à la personne ayant inspiré Dumas ([Marie Duplessis](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marie_Duplessis)) ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Première question: probablement le contexte tout entier, y compris une connaissance de l'ameublement de l'époque. Sur la base du texte présenté uniquement, il est à mon avis impossible de trancher. Ce serait donc un problème de référence culturelle plus que de langage.
- Deuxième question: effectivement, une compréhension de la culture autour de ce passage serait pour moi la clé de la sémantique de ce *perse*, plus que le langage.
- Quoique - ne dirait-on pas plutôt *persane* que *perse*, s'il s'agissait de *Perse*? Ceci dit, cette [référence](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/perse//2) ferait pencher la balance plutôt en faveur... d'un type d'étoffe *que l'on croyait venir de Perse*, sans que la couleur soit précisément fixée.
- Peut-être indécidable (*persan* ou *bleu/gris*?), même avec le contexte culturel, car le mot *perse* en soi semble avoir plusieurs significations. Cf exemples donnés par [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/perse//2) pour *perse* en tant que substantif féminin, mis en apposition pour prendre la fonction d'un adjectif (!): *Un joli boudoir tendu d'une étoffe **perse** à fond gris perle (Ponson du Terr.,Rocambole,t.1, 1859, p.33).* ou bien, rarement, en tant que substantif masculin: *L'inutile boudoir était tendu de ce vieux **perse** après lequel courent aujourd'hui tous les amateurs du genre dit Pompadour (Balzac,Vieille fille, 1836, p.304).* Varius multiplex multiformis, donc indécidable, ou tout du moins mystérieux.
- En fin de compte, je me demande si dans ce cas, *pers, perse* n'était pas en fait simplement une expression littéraire toute faite pour désigner un type d'ameublement/tenture/étoffe d'origine "orientale" que le lecteur aurait reconnu comme étranger et exotique, venant de "l'Orient" sans que cela soit très précis: le mot *pers* était peut-être déjà rare au XIXe siècle?

Comment: Merci ! L'apposition du substantif _perse_ pour la toile peinte ds. l'exemple de Ponson, vraiment vraiment excellent.

Comment: Oui - mais cela ne vous aide pas si vous voulez décider s'il s'agit de la Perse ou de bleu/gris :-)

Comment: Néanmoins. Mais vous aurez noté qu'il ne fait absolument aucun doute que le LBU classe l'exemple pour la couleur ; il introduit l'exemple avec trois autres dans 555, dédié exclusivement aux adjectifs de couleurs, et les 4 exemples sont introduits par une remarque à l'effet que pers s'applique souvent aux yeux mais aussi à d'autres réalités, et que le féminin est attesté. Je suis certain de ne jamais avoir entendu _perse_ pour la couleur, ce qui veut sans doute dire que je ne l'ai jamais compris vu l'homonymie, et heureusement (?) j'ai peu lu mes classiques donc eu peu de chances de me tromper!

Comment: Le mot _pers_ pour la couleur est devenu rare - nous ne l'utilisons plus couramment, et certainement pas en conversation courante. Je ne serais pas surpris qu'une majorité de Français ne comprenne plus ce mot.

Comment: Ici votre manque de surprise potentiel me surprend, je serais sans doute déçu, comme c'est vraiment un syntagme incontournable avec _yeux_, mais en fait je ne sais pas si on le connaît bien ou non. Mais l'accord au féminin par exemple, ça pour moi c'est inusité, mais comme j'ai dit je ne suis pas surpris. Merci !

Comment: J"ai fait un rapide sondage informelle autour de moi, et _pers_ était assez inconnu. Je pense que c'est bel et bien un mot devenu au moins _littéraire_. On pourrait confirmer avec ngrams. Les _yeux bleux_: tous les jours. Les _yeux pers_: très rarement, voire jamais en conversation.

Answer (score 2):

> Elles entrèrent dans une chambre tapissée de toile imprimée.

« Étoffe perse » comme « [toile perse](https://1001origines.net/origine/sens-de-perse.html) » désignait un tissu peint ou imprimé initialement originaire d'Inde, d'ailleurs aussi appelé [indienne](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indienne_(tissu)). Perse désigne l'origine, pas la couleur, en raison du point de passage obligé des marchandises en provenance d'Inde et autres pays d'Orient. La couleur des « toiles perses » n'est pas forcément définie mais le rouge semble avoir été dominant. Les « toiles perses » de l'époque de Dumas étaient très probablement d'origine européenne.

Le mot « [persienne](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/persienne) », de « persien » ancien synonyme de « persan », est lié à cette même étymologie.

L'adjectif « [pers / perse](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pers) » est lui aussi, dès son apparition en Latin, lié à l'origine géographique mais représente une couleur, ici le bleu/vert, exactement comme « [turquoise](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/turquoise) » qui vient de l'ancien français « turcois » = turc.

Comment: Merci ! Si les toiles perses avaient été généralement de couleur perse, c'eût été une bien étrange coïncidence ou fausse métonymie ou je ne sais trop. La nébuleuse pers/perse est bien intéressante. Par ailleurs je ne comprends toujours pas comment le LBU peut trancher dans ce cas-ci, a fortiori avec une homonymie encore plus forte que je ne l'avais présumé, tel qu'illustré par vos réponses.

Comment: Very easy question: tendu d'étoffe perse means: hung with Persian cloth. L'adjectif perse pour l'aire géographique, disons, ne change pas au féminin et la Perse, c'est l'Iran (aujourd'hui), pas l'Inde.

Comment: @Lambie Perse est le nom du pays aussi appelé Iran, il est utilisé ici comme un adjectif, mais ce n'est pas un adjectif, un peu comme on dit « un chapeau panama » au lieu de « un chapeau panaméen ». L'adjectif correspondant à Perse est persan(e), voire persien(ne). Le tissu dont il est question ici était cependant originaire d'Inde, ou du style des tissus originaire d'Inde, mais certainement pas de Perse qui était seulement le lieu de passage des caravanes transportant les produits d'orient à destination de la méditerranée via les routes de la soie.

Comment: @jlliagre Les Lettres Persanes, n'est-ce pas? Je sais. :)

Comment: @jlliagre - CNRTL donne _perse_ à la fois comme adjectif et comme substantif. Dans l'expression _une chambre tendue d'étoffe perse_, comment décide-t-on si l'on a à faire à l'adjectif ou au substantif en apposition?

Comment: @Frank *Étoffe perse* est une expression toute faite. Il n'est absolument pas vraisemblable que Dumas ait fait un jeu de mots pour la détourner. Il est vrai que *perse* est aussi défini dans le TLFi comme un adjectif désignant ce qui est relatif à la Perse mais il est alors limité à la Perse ancienne (de l'antiquité au VIIe siècle), en concurrence avec *persique* alors que *persan* est décrit comme adjectif à utiliser pour la Perse après cette date.

Comment: @jlliagre - Je vois - le sens n'est en fait pas le même s'il s'agit d'un adjectif ou d'un substantif, et seul le substantif correspond au sens ici.